# R - Make a list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a list called ERA500 I imported from a file looking like this:

```
      Year Month Day Time   Wwind   Swind    Geop
335   1961    12   1   12   3.998 -10.759 514.689
336   1961    12   2   12   4.757 -11.077 506.611
337   1961    12   3   12  -2.606 -17.207 510.742
338   1961    12   4   12  -1.110 -19.290 510.655
```

It has thousands of rows just like this one. I am trying to split it up into 12 lists, 1 for each month. So I tried this:

```
Fyrsta <- list()
for (i in 1:12 ) {
    Fyrsta[i] = subset(ERA500,Month==i)
}
```

All I get from this are endless lists of only years. How can I make a list of those 12 new lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have a data frame.  In which case, just use `split`:

```
Frysta <- split(ERA500, ERA500$Month)
```

This will produce a list with 12 data frames in it, one for each month.

I should add, it sounds like this is a precursor to some kind of segmented analysis on each component of `ERA500`.  If so, you should consider looking at packages `data.table` or `dplyr` that make analysis of sub-groups of data frames very easy and efficient.

For example, this:

```
library(data.table)
data.table(ERA500)[, list(mean(Wwind), max(Swind)), by=Month]
```

Would return the mean `Wwind` and max `Swind` for each month.

Comment: Thank you, this got me back on track.

Answer (score 1):

To assign to the element of a list, use the `[[]]` syntax:

```
Fyrsta[[i]] = subset(ERA500,Month==i)
```

You can do this without the explicit loop and without predeclaring the list with `lapply`:

```
Fyrsta <- lapply(1:12, function(i) subset(ERA500, Month==i))
```

Better to use `[` to index the data frame, rather than `subset` which can cause trouble in certain uses.  Here is the syntax:

```
Fyrsta <- lapply(1:12, function(i) ERA500[ERA500$Month==i,])
```